# JavaFX TileLIST

Tags: user-interface, javafx, tilelist

Does anyone know of JavaFX having a TileList anywhere?  I know that it's got a TilePane, but I would like to keep the functionality as provided by a List.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is a TileList? which functionality do you need?

Comment: A TileList is a regular ListView, but instead of just having Vertical and Horizontal orientation, the items are laid out in a tiled fashion.  An example in the Flex/AIR world can be found here.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d82.html

The purpose of the list is because I wanted to be able to display items in a tile fashion (like a TilePane) but I also wanted to keep the ListView functionality (mouseOver, renderer stuff and multiple item selection)

Comment: sorry I don't know how to select multiple items. I think the layout you are looking for is FlowPane. here a list of default layouts http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102

Comment: Oh, don't worry.  I know how to get a Tiled layout into the application, it's just that I can't get it to come with a SelectionModel.